# How to create a white glow border around an image

Tags: image, css, border, glow

How can I create a white glow as the border of an unknown size image?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use CSS (not supported in IE<9)

```
img {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
}
```

This will put a white glow around every image in your document, use more specific selectors to choose which images you'd like the glow around. You can change the color of course.

If you're worried about the users that don't have the latest versions of their browsers, use this:

```
img {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
}
```

For IE you can use a glow filter (not sure which browsers support it)

```
img {
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(Color=white,Strength=5);
}
```

Comment: I think this supports only IE 9+, just add:`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` to render the page in IE9 and IE10 as version IE9

Comment: Note that filter has unexpected behaviour in several elements. Apply it to a fieldset and be amazed. Also, it may leak to child elements. And it will show a ActiveX warning for the page with the dreaded yellow bar. Just avoid it. add a flat light grey shadow for IE and be done with.

Comment: Doesn't works with transparent images. Like a round png logo.

Comment: @SantoshKumar, no it doesn't, because the box-shadow can't possibly know where the non-transparent pixels of a png are. It only affects HTML elements, the <img> element itself, not the content.

Comment: @Kyle drop-shadow can though :)

Answer (score 14):

This is what you need.

```
.imageClass {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}
```

This will only work in browsers that support `-webkit-filter`.

Comment: Downvoted; -webkit-filter isn't a CSS property, and in any case would only support webkit browsers - you'd be better off also adding a non-prefixed version, and probably -moz-, -ms- and -o- prefixes, should mozilla, Microsoft or Opera (at whilst Opera 12 is still in circulation ...)

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with `box-shadow`:

```
img{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 5px #f2e1f2; 
}
```

See this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XUC5q/1/, and you can generate from here http://css3generator.com/

If you need it to work in older versions of IE, you can use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/) to emulate the box-shadow in those browsers & you can use `filter` as Kyle said like this

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(color='red', Strength='5')
```

You can generate your filter from here http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/filter/Glow.htm

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what your target browsers are. In newer ones it's [as simple as](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-shadow):

```
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
```

For older browsers you have to implement workarounds, e.g., based [on this example](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/roundshadow.html), but you will most probably need extra mark-up.

Answer (score 1):

`padding:7px;` will give you a nice looking padded in image. The padding will give you a simulated white border (or whatever border you have set). The rgba is just allowing you to do an opacity on the particular color; 0,0,0 being black. You could just as easily use any other RGB color.

Comment: This does not answer the question, and should have been a comment under an existing answer (if it was really needed in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 to create an effect like that, but then you're only going to see it in modern browsers that support box shadow, unless you use a polyfill like [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/). So, for example, you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cany2/