# Adding Glow Effect to Input Boxes and Buttons

Tags: html, css, forms, input, glow

I'm in the middle of making my html form, and I want to add effects on it.

Is it possible for `<input name="" type="text" class="" />` to have a glow effect?

Would it also be possible for the submit button to have this effect as well?

Comment: What do you mean by a 'glow effect'? Changing border color when you hover over the elements?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422790/css-create-white-glow-around-image

Comment: @Veger: yup, something like that. When a user clicks or starts to input text, the box glows, similar to outer glow in photoshop.

Comment: @js1568: this is a different matter to the question you linked. :)

Answer (score 2):

This Works for all inputs of class Button

```
input.Button {
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px Green;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px Green;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px Green;
}
```

Per @Imoda

This works for all inputs of type text

```
input[type='text'] {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #ffffff;
}
```

And to get it only on hover:

```
input[type='text']:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? It works just fine in modern browsers.

Comment: @Mae Guff try it with `input[type="text"] { ... }` as your selector instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create objects or artwork via Photoshop or Fireworks, then import that graphic into your development with your CSS file. Example:

```
div#btn {
background-position: top right;
position:absolute; */
margin:0px 0px; padding:0px;
text-align:center;
background-image: url(images/bg1.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Then in your HTML, just call that div on your button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess this can be applied to buttons, but i like to have this glow effect in action. I mean, when the user hovers or starts to type then the input box glows :)

Answer (score 0):

This will select your inputs that are the "text" type. Then change the `#FFFFFF` to whatever colour you wish. In theory this should work. If it doesn't, add `inset` directly after each colon. It's not an exact `outer-glow` replication, but I believe it'll suit your needs.

```
input[type='text'] {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #ffffff;
}
```