# Glowing image with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, glow

I have two images. One that is normal, and another that is more colourised. I want to have this image displaying on top of the other and having a "glowing" effect where it switches between transparent and opaque every second or so. I also need to stop this effect when the user presses a particular button. How would I go about doing this with jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: Also consider css animations!

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use CSS, since the animation must be stopped in response to a button.

Comment: setup a demo fiddle. (http://jsbin.com) Show us how your HTML / CSS looks like.

Comment: @DanielMarshall you can always remove the animation from css when button clicked

Comment: @Roko C. Bulja http://jsbin.com/akewiz/2/edit#javascript,html

Comment: Click the img: http://jsfiddle.net/37Esn/2/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422790/css-create-white-glow-around-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/atofif/250/edit)*

[html](/questions/tagged/html):

```
<button id="stop">STOP IT!</button>

<div class="images">
     <img src="img1.jpg" />
     <img src="img2.jpg" class="glowed"/>
</div>
```

[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):

```
var playing = true;

function loop(){
  if(playing){
    $('.images img:eq(1)').fadeIn(700, function(){
      $(this).fadeOut(700,loop);
    });
  }
}

loop(); // start loop


$('#stop').click(function(){
  playing=0;
});
```

Just position the two images absolute:

```
  .images img{
    position:absolute;
  }

  .glowed{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 2px #cf5
  }
```

I used [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) box shadow, but you could use a *glowed* .png image instead.