# Applying Image Filter - creating aura image

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I want to create function similar to this

http://www.astrolantis.de/en/aura.php#anker_aura

I have tried it in PHP using Image filters

http://filmidrama.com/imagefilter/

But I am not able to create aura effect as it is done in the website.

Can you please guide me how should I proceed?

For Details about Aura:
Every person has a special and individual aura. Sensible people have another aura-signature of frequencies. Their energy contains special features. By using a special photo resonance method it is possible to reconstruct an individual aura profile.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure how you are trying to create the Aura effect. One way of doing it is to use simple CSS3 (not supported in IE<9)

```
img
{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
}
```

This will put a white glow around every image. You can use more specific selectors to choose which images you'd like the glow around.

For people that don't have the latest versions of their browsers, you can do something like this:

```
img
{
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
}
```

For IE you can use a glow filter

```
img
{
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(Color=white,Strength=5);
}
```

you can see more [CSS: create white glow around image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6422827/1380867) and a Thanks to  [Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287047/kyle).